# Building a binary statically to run on another distro (AqBanking)

Tags: static-linking

I want to run AqBanking on a server that does not allow installation of packages for security reasons.

My idea was to link a static binary.

I basically did this:

```
apt-get source aqbanking-tools
apt-get build-dep aqbanking-tools
./configure
make SHARED=0 CC='gcc -static'
```

I looks like the option is also applied:

```
/bin/bash ../../../libtool  --tag=CC   --mode=link gcc -static -fvisibility=hidden -g -O2 -g -Wall -Wdeclaration-after-statement  -g -o aqbanking-cli main.o /home/self/libaqbanking-5.7.8/src/plugins/backends/aqhbci/plugin/libaqhbci.la /home/self/libaqbanking-5.7.8/src/libs/aqbanking/libaqbanking.la -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -lgwenhywfar -lstdc++ 
libtool: link: gcc -fvisibility=hidden -g -O2 -g -Wall -Wdeclaration-after-statement -g -o aqbanking-cli main.o  /home/self/libaqbanking-5.7.8/src/plugins/backends/aqhbci/plugin/.libs/libaqhbci.a -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu /home/self/libaqbanking-5.7.8/src/libs/aqbanking/.libs/libaqbanking.a -lgmp -lgwenhywfar -lstdc++
```

But after copying `aqbanking-cli` to another computer I am getting:

```
./aqbanking-cli 
./aqbanking-cli: error while loading shared libraries: libgwenhywfar.so.60: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

What can I do to get a binary which runs everywhere?

*EDIT*: libgwenhywfar is a library not contained in the sources of the package. It is already present on the build system. How to link it together to the final binary?

*EDIT2*: I am building on Ubuntu 18.04 and want to run on Debian 8 --- maybe that is a problem as well. I would be okay to build on Debian 8 as well, just cannot install system packages on the target system.